# a button style like in addressbook and ibooks

Tags: iphone, uikit

I'd like to style my buttons like apple does in addressbook and ibooks for example (light grey boarder, small rounds...). how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are referring to a  `UITableViewCell` when it is in its grouped table style format.

Create a UITableView and change it to the grouped style mode. Then each cell will be rounded, with a gray border. Here is the code for changing it:

```
UITableView* tableView = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(your frame) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

You can also do this in Interface Builder under the Table View's properties. Now add data to the Table View and it's cells will appear how they do in Address Book and iBooks.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation: what i ment was the style of the EDIT and SHARE-button on the bottom of the right page.

Comment: May look here: http://www.rivacrmintegration.com/wp-content/uploads/sync-crm-ipad-021.png

Comment: @einheitswurzel I'll reply in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a UIButton. Text color should be `[UIColor grayColor]`  the border color should be `[UIColor grayColor]` and the background should be `[UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: hi, thanks, but i thinks that's not all. I think the radius of the rounded corners is different and there's some kind of inner or outer shadow, don't you think that too?

Comment: You can set a shadow. And the radius doesn't seem different to me. I am almost sure it is a UIButton. Read the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html